# Create Password Field in webpart properties

Tags: web-part, visual-web-part, custom-web-part-property, web-part-property

I have created a custom web-part. this web-part have a custom web-part properties. i want a Password field in this property.

How can i do this ?

Any help will appreciated ..

Comment: you can do this using toolpart

Answer (score 1):

I guess using a webpart toolpart will accomplish this.

Two links I found by just googling "webpart toolpart":
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584178(v=office.11).aspx

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/SharePoint-Creating-a-Custom-ToolPart-for-a-Custom-Web-Part.aspx